# Protect your API key from being stolen or abused

Tags: node.js, api, express

Hello so I would like to ask what are the other ways of protecting your api from being abused or DDOS'ed by your envious enemies?

I have this simple website of mine that uses Google API and some homebrew API that is deployed in Heroku.

My first idea is to simply never call an API on the front end let the webhost server call everything first and load the data with the webpage making it so that when the page is loaded there is no trace of your API in the front end.

But sometimes when your websites contains an auto-updating data your api has to be in the front end. In scenarios such as these what are other "pro" measures i can take so that i can protect my API.

I have heard that there are ways that involves OAuth and SSL ? how do they basically work?

My API are deployed to Heroku and is created using Node.Js express library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well APIs that are in the front end can and will be stolen, its just a matter of when. It is the nature APIs. Even API in the app can be retrieved by reading its assembly.

What you can do though is limit what the user can do to your API in server side, either place timeout, how fast is this specific device calling you API, then simply lock out the uses IP address for a day or so.

There is no way around it, the whole industry has to change in order for you to completely hide APIs.